# How to break line by each element unit

Tags: html, css

The element part in the width that I appointed is in present state,
 it is started a new line on the way. 
How to break line by each element unit

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis">
<title>no title document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.sample {
    width: 220px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sample">
<a href="#">aaaa</a>
<a href="#">bbbb</a>
<a href="#">cc</a>
<a href="#">ddddd</a>
<a href="#">eee</a>
<a href="#">fff</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: block` for `<a>`:

```
<!--
    .sample {
        width: 220px;
    }

    .sample a {
        display: block;
    }
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean but you can use `<br/>` tags

```
<body>
<div class="sample">
<a href="#">aaaa</a><br/>
<a href="#">bbbb</a><br/>
<a href="#">cc</a><br/>
<a href="#">ddddd</a><br/>
<a href="#">eee</a><br/>
<a href="#">fff</a><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use unordered list instead of this!

- element
- element
- element
- element

If you explicit want a linebreak,  mark up a br, or set display: block css parameter to the 'a' tags.

```
.sample a{
      display: block;
}
```

Comment: A list is the best solution, but the OP probably doesn't want bullet points or indentation, in which case you need to add `list-style:none` on the `li` element, and `padding:0` on the `ul` element.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `<a>` elements into block. Block elements will break unless floated.

Add this into your CSS or style:

```
a { display: block; }
```